# Can one create a custom type in postgres without writing functions in C?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I'm trying to create a type to store color hexes preferably in byte form. I followed all the instructions in postgres docs here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createtype.html
and found the part where it says `CREATE FUNCTION my_box_in_function(cstring) RETURNS box AS ... ;` a bit... unsettling. What goes in the ellipses? Turns out that was justified as I cannot find any example of creating a simple data type without custom PG functions written in C.
My best attempt was this:

```
CREATE TYPE color;
CREATE FUNCTION color_in(cstring) RETURNS color AS $$
    BEGIN
        RETURN decode($1::text, 'hex')::color;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL IMMUTABLE RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;
CREATE FUNCTION color_out(color) RETURNS cstring AS $$
    BEGIN
        RETURN encode($1::bytea, 'hex')::text;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL IMMUTABLE RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;

CREATE TYPE color (
    INTERNALLENGTH = 3,
    LIKE = bytea,
    INPUT = color_in,
    OUTPUT = color_out
);
```

This yields the error:

```
NOTICE:  return type color is only a shell
ERROR:  PL/pgSQL functions cannot return type color
```

Similar error if I use Language SQL or default to SPL.
The example in-out functions are listed here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/xtypes.html. The only example functions are written in C. Am I correct in assuming this is the only way to write a UDT in postgres? Is there another way? My goal is to have the colors stored as bytes but have their native text form be hexadecimal (for the purposes of dumping, restoring, and casting from raw).

Comment: How about you put the definition at the bottom of your code block at the top instead?

Comment: @Politank: Wouldn't work, it would complain that `color_in`, doesn't exist.

Comment: FYI, one of the Postgres devs wrote a [detailed tutorial on user-defined types](https://wiki.postgresql.org/images/a/a5/PGConf-EU-2013-User-Defined-Datatype.pdf), and used 24-bit RGB colours as the example. All that's left for you to do is compile it.

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/datatype-pseudo.html

> Functions coded in procedural languages can use pseudo-types only as
> allowed by their implementation languages. At present the procedural
> languages all forbid use of a pseudo-type as argument type, and allow
> only void and record as a result type (plus trigger when the function
> is used as a trigger). Some also support polymorphic functions using
> the types anyelement, anyarray, anynonarray, anyenum, and anyrange.

And from the docs for create type
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/sql-createtype.html

> The input function can be declared as taking one argument of type
> cstring, or as taking three arguments of types cstring, oid, integer.
>
> The output function must return type cstring.

Given the above:

1. Base data type input and output functions use cstring.
2. Procedural languages can not use cstring.
3. Base data type functions can't be written in procedural language.
4. Defining a base data type can't be done purely in procedural languages.

You can use pre-existing input and output functions, but I don't think
that any of them will directly get you a hex string.  The closest
is probably the \x hex escaped bytea, but you'd have a \x at the beginning of your text representation.  If you're willing to cast to and from text, I think you could create a type using bytea_in and bytea_out and writing custom casts to and from text.  You'd have to explicitly cast to avoid the \x though.